# In Pubnub how to make two subscribers subscribed to a channel member of a group, to subscribe each other using object listeners in javascript?

Tags: pubnub

Me and my team mate created a app using pubnub server. We need to add a function where it should make subscribers who are members of a channelgroup, need to subscribe eachother while joining the group using object listeners in membership handling.

I tried a function usinf pubnub.herenow and presence event, but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on what you have posted, you are not headed in the right direction. But it could be the PubNub terminology you are using is not be used in the proper context or you are mixing up terminology that is "PubNub accurate". As the Community mentioned, this is a pretty open-ended question. I would try using PubNub Support for more insights: support@pubnub.com. It's free, fast and high quality.

Comment: I would also visit (or revisit) the Docs to get some base understanding of what Channel Groups (for subscribing to lots of channels) are vs. PN Objects - aka Metadata, AppContext (for creating Channel:User Memberships), and what PN Functions can do for you. 
https://www.pubnub.com/docs/general/channels/overview